# Application Window Title Bar Background Image

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to set a background image for the [Application Window Title Bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP9) of Mac OS X apps? An example would be the brown strip found across the top of the Notes and Calendar Apps. [image]

I am making the transition from iOS to Mac OS and was hoping for an equivalent of:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Toolbar_bg_norm~iphone.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I poked around the docs to no avail. I see that [a question about title bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798605/change-color-of-title-bar-in-cocoa) was asked previously, but it is a couple years old. I am hopeful that there has been an update since then that makes this more accessible.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any out-of-the box method like on iOS. However, you could have a look at the quite popular [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) (you can adjust the titlebar height in case you're wondering). With it, you can easily provide a NSView that will be used in the titlebar or you can provide your own [drawing code](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow#using-your-own-drawing-code) that draws you desired image.