# Sublime Text 3 Borderless? / General python applications borderless

Tags: python, macos, window, sublimetext, borderless

Is it possible to make Sublime Text 3 borderless similar to how it is in ubuntu?

In other words, is is possible to get rid of the gray bar at the top, or theme the gray bar at least to fit the rest of the theme in Sublime?

[image: Sublime With Gray Bar]

My hope is that it could look something similar to this:

[image: No Gray Bar at the top]

Again, I do understand the second one is a linux distro by the looks of it, I was hoping to make this possible on OS X though.

I know this can be done on OS X after looking at the most recent version of Spotify. There is no gray bar at the top. The bar blends with the rest of the theme, similar to how iOS 7 works it seems.

Comment: This is possible in Cocoa [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798605/change-color-of-title-bar-in-cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798605/change-color-of-title-bar-in-cocoa) so is possible for ST3 to do but I very very very much hope it never does. The Mac Human Interface Guidelines exist for a very long list of very good reasons. Having a Mac App look like a Mac App is part of the package you buy into with a Mac. Embracing those constraints is part of the deal. For those that reject that idea (which is valid) another OS may be a better fit.

Comment: @duncan Looks great with Spotify. Why not.