# Changing the background color of the unified NSToolbar (in Yosemite)

Tags: cocoa, swift

I want to have a unified toolbar and therefore I found this post:

[How can I create Yosemite-style unified toolbar in Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023000/how-can-i-create-yosemite-style-unified-toolbar-in-interface-builder)

`self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden`

works perfect.

But is there a way to change the background color for the toolbar? I tried with `self.window.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)`, but this only brings a complete black toolbar (that's too dark). I want to have a custom color.

Comment: Yes. A lot of applications in the Mac App Store do sth. like that. Look at Affinity Designer for example)

Answer (score 7):

This one works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692893/2062613

1. Set the window to textured in IB (I don't see a possibility to do it at runtime)
2. Use this code:

   ```
   self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden
   self.window.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
   ```

**UPDATE**:

To prevent, that the toolbar becomes transparent in Yosemite (if you have a scrollview below the Toolbar), use this code:

```
self.window.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameAqua)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this solution to customize the title bar. However, since 10.15.4 and apparently on Big Sur, the toolbar is broken. If you have a toolbar with the window, the toolbar will placed on the top edge of the window, as if there is no title bar.