# Changing colour of toolbar in window in Mac using Swift code

Tags: swift, cocoa

There is a requirement to change the colour of the tool bar item to red in colour for the NSWindow.

Any suggestion to do so. We use Swift code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the background color of the unified NSToolbar (in Yosemite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952202/changing-the-background-color-of-the-unified-nstoolbar-in-yosemite)

Answer (score -3):

In order to change the background color of the toolbar do the following:

```
self.toolbar.isTranslucent = false

self.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: The question is not about iOS.